# Python, finding unique words in multiple lists

Tags: python, string, list, loops, sorting

I have the following code:

```
 a= ['hello','how','are','hello','you']
 b= ['hello','how','you','today']
 len_b=len(b)

 for word in a:

      count=0
      while count < len_b:

           if word == b[count]:       
               a.remove(word)
               break

           else:
               count=count+1

 print a
```

The goal is that it basically outputs (contents of list a)-(contents of list b)
so the wanted result in this case would be a = ['are','hello']

but when i run my code i get a= ['how','are','you']

can anybody either point out what is wrong with my implementation, or is there another better way to solve this?

Comment: Don't change the length of a list while iterating over it. Also, unless order is relevant, you could just `print set(a) - set(b)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because you are mutating the list `a` while iterating over it.

If you want to solve it correctly, you can try the below method. It uses list comprehension and dictionary to keep track of the number of words in the resulting set:

```
>>> a = ['hello','how','are','hello','you']
>>> b = ['hello','how','you','today']
>>> 
>>> cnt_a = {}
>>> for w in a:
...     cnt_a[w] = cnt_a.get(w, 0) + 1
... 
>>> for w in b:
...     if w in cnt_a:
...         cnt_a[w] -= 1
...         if cnt_a[w] == 0:
...             del cnt_a[w]
... 
>>> [y for k, v in cnt_a.items() for y in [k] * v]
['hello', 'are']
```

It works well in case where there are duplicates, even in the resulting list. However it may not preserve the order, but it can be easily modify to do this if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. order is not important for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set` to get all non duplicate elements

So you could do `set(a) - set(b)` for the difference of sets

Comment: this works to an extent in the fact that it gives me whatever words  occur in a and never in b, but i still dont get the result i am looking for, it gives me a= ['are'] instead of a = ['are','hello']

Answer (score 0):

`set(a+b)` is alright, too. You can use sets to get unique elements.